# execute all tests (gtest) from library

Tags: c++, googletest

I have a foo library in c++, and I am using gtest as testing framework.

I want to create testFoo executable which calls runTests which is defined in statically linked testFoo library which contains all tests for statically linked foo library.

I have created all that I am written, but google test shows me "Empty test suite."

testFooLib.h

```
int runTests(int argc, char* argv[]);
```

testFooLib.cpp

```
int runTests(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

If I put

```
TEST(Testing, someTest){
    EXPECT_EQ(true, true);
}
```

in testFooLib.cpp, this test is found, but if I put it in some other cpp it will not be found.

testFooExecutable.h

```
#include "testFooLib.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    return runTests(argc, argv);
}
```

I have some tests in project, I don't want to pollute my post with it...
update, I have put tests in code.
I have same problem as here [important-note-for-visual-c-users](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/Primer.md#important-note-for-visual-c-users).

Note: I have tried with clang, gcc and msvc and result is always the same.

Comment: please, pollute the post. From what you included the problem cannot be seen since everything seems ok. How do you define and then include the tests? From the code given it seems you don't include the code of the tests anywhere so no wonder gtest does not find it.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that by design GTest picks up only TEST() cases defined in the .exe project. Those from static library are ignored.

Check this configuration:

Build gtest lib as a static library.
Put tests in .cpp (TEST() macro, ...) into the project which creates the executable.
GTest initialization should be called from main in .exe project:

```
 ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
 return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
```